# Unable to Toggle a Class in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I have this function for adding / removing things from a cart (it is in coffeescript... but I can make it js if need be):

```
$('.cart-link').bind('ajax:success', (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
    current_link = $(this)
    icon = $(current_link).find('i') //the cart icon
    $(icon).toggleClass('icon-ico-addcart icon-ico-removecart') //if it was add, make it remove and vice versa

    new_path = data['new_path']
    $(current_link).attr('href', new_path)

    if data['cart_size']
      $('span.badge.cart-badge').text(data['cart_size'])
    else
      $('span.badge.cart-badge').text('')
```

Most of the code works. It changes the `href` correctly, it updates the number in the badge. The only thing that doesn't work is the toggle class, and I cannot figure out why. If I run these commands in the console, it works. What am I missing?

I tried creating a separate function to see if it had one class then add one and remove the old class, but that didn't work either.

The output of:

```
console.log current_link
console.log icon
```

is

```
[a.cart-link, context: a.cart-link]
    0: a.cart-link
    context: a.cart-link
    length: 1
    __proto__: jQuery[0]

[prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1], context: a.cart-link, selector: "i"]
    context: a.cart-link
    length: 0
    prevObject: jQuery.fn.init[1]
    selector: "i"
    __proto__: jQuery[0]
```

icon.length returns 0 for some reason? Here is the html:

```
<a class="cart-link" data-disable-with="" data-method="post" data-no-turbolink="true" data-remote="true" href="/en/cart/89/remove" rel="nofollow">
  <img alt="pic" class="product" src="/assets/product1.png">
  <i class="icon-ico-addcart icon"></i>
</a>
```

Comment: Not sure, but try [ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/)

Comment: I guess I could try that, but like I said, everything in the code block is firing except that one line.

Comment: I don't think this is the problem, but there's no need to re-wrap `icon` there. `$().find()` returns a jQuery collection already. For debugging, I would try `console.log(icon.length)` to make sure that you actually found something.

Comment: Verify that `current_link` and `icon` are populated as you expect them to be.

Comment: If you are not sure, why mark as duplicate? It isn't related to that question.

Comment: @Tushar this question isn't a duplicate to the question you cited.

Comment: @Jeff try `console.log icon.length`. I can't tell from that output if it has any contents or not.

Comment: it looks to me as though `icon` has a length of 0, so it's empty.

Comment: I figured it out.... I am using the "disable with" option so that when it is adding to the cart, the user won't keep clicking, but this is causing the icon to be non-existant when my selector is looking for it.

Comment: @Jeff it's unmarked as duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What caused my issue was the `disable_with` attribute in the data field:

```
= link_to ... , data: { no_turbolink: true, disable_with: '' }, class: 'cart-link', method: :post, :remote => true do
...
```

It is a nice convenience method, but apparently, it makes all children unselectable. First, I removed that line:

```
= link_to ... , data: { no_turbolink: true}, class: 'cart-link', method: :post, :remote => true do
...
```

Then in my coffee.js file:

```
//add this function to simulate the disabled link feature
$('.cart-link').click(->
    current_link = $(this)
    current_link.hide()
  )

// after successful ajax, i need to show the link again.
$('.cart-link').bind('ajax:success', (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
    current_link = $(this)
    icon = $(current_link).find('i') //the cart icon
    $(icon).toggleClass('icon-ico-addcart icon-ico-removecart') //if it was add, make it remove and vice versa
    new_path = data['new_path']
    $(current_link).attr('href', new_path)
    if data['cart_size']
      $('span.badge.cart-badge').text(data['cart_size'])
    else
      $('span.badge.cart-badge').text('')
    // ADD THIS LINE
    current_link.show()
```

This is what worked for me.